# Координаты элемента относительно основного экрана

Tags: c#, wpf

Я записываю вот такие данные в переменные.

```
        double x = Canvas.GetLeft(rect);
        double y = Canvas.GetTop(rect);
```

Мне же нужно получить их относительно верхнего левого угла основного экрана.

Каким образом их получить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
public static Point ElementPointToScreenPoint(UIElement element, Point pointOnElement)
{
    return element.PointToScreen(pointOnElement);
}


var PointOnScreen = ElementPointToScreenPoint(Canvas,new Point(x,y));
```

Comment: А если нужны не экранные координаты, а виртуальные чтобы не было проблем при масштабировании Windows (или при DPI отличном от 96)

Comment: @Vipz как получить текущее системное DPI - написано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701606/8674428

Comment: Но PointToScreen скорее всего и так возвращает "виртуальные" координаты (т.е. device-independent units), так что ничего переводить не надо.